# Same HASH value, different files - empty strings

Tags: downloads, iso, checksums, sha256

Edited question for posterity: The reason my resulting hash values were the same is that the I'm computing checksums of two .iso files which contain "empty strings."

I attempted to verify two different ISO files and didn't notice they had not completed downloading. Both files generated the same checksum, sha256sum: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
This the same checksum you would get for any empty string.

I had amended my original question to ask "What thing am testing to get the results I got?" The answer is, "an empty string."

I'm editing this because my original question and subsequent edits left a confusing question. It's answered.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely, that two different files have the same `sha256sum`. I suspect that your two iso files have been overwritten by some other file. You can check the file sizes with `ls -l`

Comment: ... you will likely find that both files are empty. See for example [SHA-256 hash of null input?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26133/sha-256-hash-of-null-input)

Comment: We ought to keep in mind that it is unlikely but not impossible to have two different files with the same hash value.  If that were not the case, then *any* file (regardless of size) could be reduced to 64 bytes.  Clearly...that's impossible.  So the mapping cannot be 1-to-1.

Many files must map to a single hash value.  It's just unlikely.

Comment: If you're comparing two files, calculating and comparing their hash values is one thing you can do.  But don't forget the obvious...for example, comparing their file sizes.  Or, comparing the first X bytes.  These two comparisons will be quicker than calculating a hash value since this has to completely read the file.  cmp has the advantage of stopping once you find a difference, but you are also reading two files from disk at the same time...

Comment: @steeldriver - You're right, that's the value of an empty string. Expanded question in OP.

Comment: @MAChitgarha: The generated values are different than those downloaded from the sites.

Comment: Whatr they are telling you is that the ISO files are empty (check their size, they must be 0 bytes). Something cancelled the download, or your filesystem is broken. Try this: `touch foobar; sha256sum foobar` and you will get the same `e3b0c4....2b855` value for that empty file.

Comment: @xeniod, please call that the answer. My downloads from Mint and Ubuntu continue to be interrupted, while other sites work. The process works properly with complete downloads.

Comment: @steeldriver That's as good as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Do the files really differ? Use this command to know:

```
cmp path/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso path/linuxmint-19-cinnamon-64bit-v2.iso
```

If there are no differences, you should check their hash values from where you downloaded those files. They exist with a guide on [the Linux Mint's site](https://linuxmint.com/verify.php).